# Not deleting from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete users after clicking on icon, but nothing happens, just refreshing the page.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root");
$mysqli->select_db("maturita");

if($_POST && $_POST["del_us"])
{
   $ask = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
}
header("Location: manage_users.php");
?>
```

Edit: So, posting the full code. Maybe you will undterstand my thinking and then help me.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "maturita");
?>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>First Name</th> 
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Rights</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM users";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
{

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($query)) 
    {
?>      
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->rights; ?></td>
    <td><a name="del_us" href="delete_user.php"><i name="del_us" class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}       
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the id which you're using in the query is available in the database?

Comment: What is the content of `$_POST`? You are sending the form via `POST` but you are taking the `id` from `GET` - you should be consistent with your data-handling.

Comment: You will be doing either a `POST` or a `GET` request. It seems illogical to check if there is a `POST` value for `"del_us"`, but at the same time a `GET` value for `"id"` ?

Comment: so many questions/answers and none accepted/marked as closed.

Comment: and the POST/GET arrays are coming from where exactly?

Comment: it's anybody's ballgame to which I don't want to play. Either you post your full code or debug it; there are many tools at your disposal, you should use them.

Comment: you are not posting nether getting the id value.

Comment: `<a name="del_us" href="delete_user.php"><i name="del_us"` you don't really expect those to "POST" do you? I think you should go back to reading the official PHP manuals and tutorials. You've been asking a lot of questions since you first opened your account here, with absolutely no results or solutions accepted.

Comment: I'm afraid that this question will not be seeing an accepted answer in its present state since it requires a total rewrite.

Comment: Cool story bro. Was there a *question*? Or was this just intended to be a status report? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so tried to add thw whole code

Comment: btw the name attribute for a tags is not supported in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Assuming your conditional is correct and the variable you want as an id is `$_POST["del_us"]` then

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root");
$mysqli->select_db("maturita");

if($_POST && $_POST["del_us"])
{
   $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["del_us"]);
   $ask = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
}
header("Location: manage_users.php");
?>
```

Where I've also escaped the posted variable to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
if($_POST && $_POST["del_us"])
{
   $ask = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
}
```

Looks a bit wierd to me

Or you are using GET method so your if is wrong and then you have to change your code like this:

```
if($_GET && $_GET["del_us"])
{
   $ask = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
}
```

assuming that "del_us" and "id" are two different variables
or probably you need to change your query:

```
if($_POST && $_POST["del_us"])
{
   $ask = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");
}
```

Comment: The del_us is the name of the button. I was thinking like of the button was pressed then delete user with his id

Comment: @HankyPanky before introducing the SQL injection affaire I'd like to understand what is he exactly doing

Comment: It's amazing how answers get more attention than comments (up there) *lol!* - well, I'm out; good luck y'all.

Comment: buttin has been added

Comment: del_us is not a button but an a tag and there is not a form in your html